# Renderizar a json modelo con campo de otro modelo en Api Rest

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, rest

Estoy haciendo una Api Rest. Tengo un modelo llamado Institute, el está relacionado con el modelo City:

```
class Institute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
end
```

En el método index del controlador institutes_controller quiero que en lugar de la columna city_id me muestre el nombre de la ciudad, por lo que hago esto:

```
def index
  @institutes = Institute.select([:id, :city_id, 'cities.name as city', :code, :name, :created_at, :updated_at]).joins(:city).all

  render json: @institutes
end
```

Pero eso me está renderizando no sólo el nombre de la ciudad sino todo el registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para que me muestre los campos del modelo Institute y el nombre de la ciudad, y no todos los campos del registro ciudad?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `as_json` con las opciones `include` y `only`; ejemplo:

```
@institutes = Institute.all.as_json(include: { city: { only: :name })
```

Con el código anterior tendrías una llave en tu JSON similar a la siguiente (solo muestro los primeros dos atributos del objeto):

```
{ 
  "id": 0,
  "code": "COYONGAL",
  "city": {
    "name": "SANTA MARTA"
  }
}
```

Si lo que deseas es agregar únicamente el valor, omitiendo la llave anidada, podrías generar un método dentro de `Institute` que obtenga el nombre y utilizar la opción `methods` dentro del método `as_json`; ejemplo:

institute.rb

```
class Institute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city

  def city_name
    city.name
  end
end
```

institutes_controller.rb

```
def index
  @institutes = Institute.all.as_json(methods: :city_name)

  render json: @institutes
end
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
{ 
  "id": 0,
  "code": "COYONGAL",
  "city_name": "SANTA MARTA"
}
```

---

Puedes ver más opciones para generar el JSON en la [documentación de Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json).

Comment: La opción de crear el método city_name es la que usaré.  Muchas gracias.